# Initial settings in MPI program

Tags: c++, mpi

I would like to allow the user to set settings in the application via the command line.

On experimentation, I found that I can only set the variables in the first method using this method; therefore I realised I needed to use send and receive. However my code doesnt work

Below is my code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  cout << "Enter v" << endl;
  double v;
  cin >> v;
  cout << v << endl;

  MPI::Init(argc,argv);

  int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
  int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();

  if (rank == 0)
  {
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&v, 8, MPI_DOUBLE, v, 1);
  }
  else
  {
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&v, 8, MPI_DOUBLE, v, 1, );
  }

  cout << "My rank is " << rank <<". My v is " << v << endl; 
  MPI::Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

it reports this:

```
enter v
5
5
enter v
2.23533e-317
enter v
2.23533e-317
enter v
2.23533e-317
0 - MPI_SEND : Invalid rank 5
[0]  Aborting program !
[0] Aborting program!
p0_11420:  p4_error: : 8262
Killed by signal 2.
Killed by signal 2.
Killed by signal 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error comes from :

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&v, 8, MPI_DOUBLE, v, 1);
```

If you want to send one double then :

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&v, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, v, 1);
```

To avoid errors, check first that v < size...The code you provided will send value v to proc v. To send the same value of parameter to all processes, use MPI_Bcast() (broadcast).

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Bcast.html

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast( &v, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0);
```

Bye,

Francis